# How do I translate the default meta tags?

Tags: i18n-l10n, 10, meta-tags

I dont see any option to translate default meta tags. Any tips?

Admin url is at admin/config/search/metatag/taxonomy_term

I am using metatag version 2.x

[image: edit custom meta tags]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

Use the "Translate" option in the list of Metatag defaults:

[image]

Method 2:

1. Go to Admin -> Configuration -> Region and language -> Configuration translation
2. Click 'List' next to 'Metatag defaults"
3. Choose the category and translate from there: [image]

If neither option is available, you probably don't have the Configuration translation module installed.

Comment: Ah that was it thank you. I didn't have config translation enabled